# Convert email signatures to Google contacts automatically?

Tags: gmail, email-signature

is there a Google gadget that can harvest email signatures and add them to my contacts?

Doesn't have to be a gadget, can be anything. just something to take my email signatures and put them into the contacts.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you are using Google apps there is an utility called [Copy2Contact](http://www.copy2contact.com/support/google/) that does the trick

Comment: I don't have the rep to comment, but regarding Copy2Contact, it now works with standard Gmail accounts. You do not have to have a Google Apps account. [www.copy2contact.com/c2c-gmail/](http://www.copy2contact.com/c2c-gmail/) Full disclosure: I'm the founder of the company.

Answer (score 1):

As copy2contact unfortunately does not work anymore, here is an alternative:
the [Evercontact Chrome Extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evercontact/hlfhddckfmifofnpklmmiboiljmengde).

The free version has some limitations, but works fine for me (so far). You just select the signature in Gmail or on any other page, and click the evercontact extention button. Can be synced to Google Contacts.